# Nested UIPageViewController

Tags: uipageviewcontroller

I maintain two instances of `UIPageViewController` inside my App as follows:

- **Outer** `UIPageViewController` (Horizontal)

  - Controller A (`UIViewController`)
  - Controller B (`UIViewController`)

    - **Inner** `UIPageViewController` (Horizontal)

      - Controller X (`UIViewController`)
      - Controller Y (`UIViewController`)

Controller B has the inner `UIPageViewController` to navigate between controller X & Y. The issue is that I can't go back to the outer `UIPageViewController` once I am inside controller B. It seems that the inner `UIPageViewController` intercepts the pan gesture and doesn't forward it to the outer `UIPageViewController`!